vlookup all records between dates
In Sheet 1 I have start date (B1) and end date (D1).

Then I have multiple sheets with a list of dates in column A and codes in column B and C, different in different sheets, for example Sheet2:

Sheet3:

In Sheet1 I'd like to get all the values of column A, B and C of all the other sheets when the date of those records are in the range of Sheet1.
In that example, this is what I'd like to get


Does your version of Excel support dynamic array formulas?

Your query needs some clarity here. Firstly, If the start date is from 4th April 2024 till 5th April 2024 then how could you achieve the desired output unless the the end date is +1 added. secondly, if the end date is till 4th May 2004 then the expected output will return all the data as given the OP. Could you explain this, is there a typo or something or i am understanding wrong

Yes, my excel version supports dynamic array formulas.

Sorry, you are right, I wrote wrong dates...start date = 5 of april, end date 6 of april.

Here is way to accomplish the desired output, also in comments OP has confirmed that the Start Date is 5th April and the End Date is 6th April, then could try the following:
As per OP's Comment

Sorry, you are right, I wrote wrong dates...start date = 5 of april,
end date 6 of april. – solquest




• Formula used in cell A3
=LET(
     _Data, WRAPROWS(TOCOL(Sheet2:Sheet3!A:C,1),3),
     FILTER(_Data,(TAKE(_Data,,1)>=B1)*(TAKE(_Data,,1)<=D1),""))


NOTE: that if one of the ranges in other sheets have blanks then the above formula will not work and will give error, if there wont be blank then good to use, otherwise here is an alternative
=LET(
     _Data, VSTACK(Sheet2:Sheet3!A1:C6),
     FILTER(_Data,(TAKE(_Data,,1)>=B1)*(TAKE(_Data,,1)<=D1),""))


Also, it is highly suggested to use Structured References aka Tables for the source Datas, this is because the formulas will automatically resize based on the increase or decrease of data in the sources. For the example, the first source table is named as Table1 while the other as Table2


=LET(
     _Data, VSTACK(Table1,Table2),
     FILTER(_Data,(TAKE(_Data,,1)>=B1)*(TAKE(_Data,,1)<=D1)))



Superb! Thank you so much for helping (never heard of those functions)
